# How to merge several list with same structure into single view?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, merge

We are using SP2013 on-premise standard edition. I have several lists with same column structure. All the lists have individual permission which allow different teams submit their report by adding daily records to list.

I need to create a single view for managers. The view will merge all the lists and provide function to sorting, ordering and filtering.

May I know how to do this without too many coding?

P.S. I have tried create a joined data source with SPD2013 and display the view on a blank (no styling at all) aspx. The data are listed correctly but I cannot do any sort, order and filter. Any good reference is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It might be help full and well explained

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/401818/SharePoint-SPSiteDataQuery-with-Example

Comment: Thanks. I have checked this page before. But it only explain what SPDataQuery did. I still not sure how to create a page, show a view bind with the merged datasource.